# How to ignore my static folder with Json Web Token (JWT)

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm using JWT to secure my app.

I created a folder named `public` who store my img.

I want to get theses images from my app.

`app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

I try to add `'/public/*` or just `'/public'` to ignore this route but when i try to get my images i receive this message : `{"message":"Invalid Token"}`

How can do to JWT ignore all url with /public/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you validate the jwt using a middleware.
I that case, just put the express.static middleware before the jwt middleware.
That way, requests to '/public' will be handled by the express.static middleware, and won't reach the jwt middleware. (This of course means that these requests will not be validated by the jwt middleware.)